# Exclude posts from get_posts()

Tags: php, wordpress

Good morning, I found many similar questions, but none of the answer fit to my problem. The point is very simple: I have a custom loop with get_posts(), and I want to exclude current post from being displayed.

The code is:

```
$args = array(
          'posts_per_page'    => 3,
          'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
          'order'             => 'ASC',
          'post_type'         => 'fasthomepress_pt',
          'post__not_in'      => array(get_the_id()),
          'meta_query'        => array(
                                    array(
                                        'key' => 'custom_richiesta',
                                        'value' => array($custom_boxes['custom_richiesta'][0] - 10000, $custom_boxes['custom_richiesta'][0] + 10000 ),
                                        'type' => 'numeric',
                                        'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
                                      )
                              )
      );
```

I tried with:

```
'post__not_in' => array(get_the_ID),
'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
'exclude'      => $post->ID,
'exclude'      => get_the_ID,
```

and with many other combinations with or without array. Of curse, current post id is correctly echoed before this loop, and if I try echo($post->ID) and echo(get_the_ID()) I have the same, correct, result.

I really don't know what's happening,
thank you very much for help,

Marco

Comment: Try removing your meta_query now for testing and check if it exculdes the current post. The syntax is correct, it may be the problem with the meta query I think so.

Comment: I solved it now, it was my mistake!! I tried this get_posts() loop inside another loop, and I didn't placed it well. I moved this loop outside the main loop and everything worked well, thank for your support!

Comment: Hi @Marco, If my answer is helpful for you and other users kindly please accept my answer. I think it's more useful than others.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try `exclude`.

```
$args = array(
      'posts_per_page'    => 3,
      'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
      'order'             => 'ASC',
      'post_type'         => 'fasthomepress_pt',
      'exclude'      => array(get_the_id()),
      'meta_query'        => array(
                                array(
                                    'key' => 'custom_richiesta',
                                    'value' => array($custom_boxes['custom_richiesta'][0] - 10000, $custom_boxes['custom_richiesta'][0] + 10000 ),
                                    'type' => 'numeric',
                                    'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
                                  )
                          )
  );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, it doesn't work, I tried with exclude ---> array() and exclude ----> values, the result is always the same.

Comment: SOLVED! It was my mistake. I tried this get_posts() loop inside another loop, and I didn't placed it well. I moved this loop outside the main loop and everything worked well, thank for your support!

Answer (score 9):

here is a function that does just that:

```
    function get_lastest_post_of_category($cat){
    $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'order'=> 'DESC', 'orderby' => 'date', 'category__in' => (array)$cat);
    $post_is = get_posts( $args );
    return $post_is[0]->ID;
}
```

Usage: say my category id is 22 then:

```
$last_post_ID = get_lastest_post_of_category(22);
```

you can also pass an array of categories to this function.

```
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 18,
     'paged'           => $paged,
    'offset'           => 0,
    'post__not_in'     => array($last_post_ID,),
    'category'         => '',
    'category_name'    => '',
    'orderby'          => 'post_date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'include'          => '',
    'exclude'          => '',
    'meta_key'         => '',
    'meta_value'       => '',
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'post_mime_type'   => '',
    'post_parent'      => '',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true
);
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```